# forecast with R

Tags: r, forecasting

I have daily data of dengue index from January 2010 to July 2015:

```
date    dengue_index
1/1/2010    0.169194109
1/2/2010    0.172350434
1/3/2010    0.174939783
1/4/2010    0.176244642
1/5/2010    0.176658068
1/6/2010    0.177815751
1/7/2010    0.17893075
1/8/2010    0.1813232
1/9/2010    0.182199531
1/10/2010   0.185091158
1/11/2010   0.185267748
1/12/2010   0.185894524
1/13/2010   0.18511499
1/14/2010   0.188080728
1/15/2010   0.190019472
…   …
7/20/2015   0.112748885
7/21/2015   0.113246022
7/22/2015   0.111755091
7/23/2015   0.112164176
7/24/2015   0.11429011
7/25/2015   0.113951836
7/26/2015   0.11319131
7/27/2015   0.112918734
```

I want to predict the values until the end of 2016 using R.

```
library(forecast)
setwd("...")
dengue_series <- read.csv(file="r_wikipedia-googletrends-model.csv",head=TRUE,sep=";")
dengue_index <- ts(dengue_series$dengue_index, frequency=7)
plot(dengue_index)
# lambda=0 -> predict positive values
fit <- auto.arima(dengue_index, lambda=0)
fit
# predict until December 2016
forecast_series <- forecast(fit, 500)
forecast_series
plot(forecast_series)
```

Problem: the prediction is not good!
[image]

How to improve the prediction?

Link to the data source:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnvc4e78t124fkd/r_wikipedia-googletrends-model.csv?dl=0

Comment: It seems like you have a monthly seasonality here too, yo need to add it. Add a binary variable to the `xreg` parameter in `auto.arima`

Comment: See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68812/auto-arima-and-prediction) for example. Though there are better ways probably see [here](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/)

Comment: Please provide an example of your data that reproduces this behaviour.

Comment: just updated my post with a link to the data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try specifying as a multi-seasonal time series object `msts`, and then forecasting using `tbats`.  `tbats` is referenced in the paper that David Arenburg mentions in the comments.

Here's an example pulled from example data in the `forecast` package for the `taylor` dataset, which has seasonal periods of 48 half-hour periods in a day, and 336 half hour periods in a week (i.e. 336 / 48 = 7).

```
x <- msts(taylor, seasonal.periods=c(48,336), ts.frequency=48, start=2000+22/52)
fit <- tbats(x)
fc <- forecast(fit)

# not shown, but the forecast seems to capture both seasonal patterns
plot(fc)
```

Also see http://users.ox.ac.uk/~mast0315/CompareUnivLoad.pdf for additional info on `taylor`

For your data set with daily data and a daily/monthly seasonal pattern, perhaps

```
tsdat <- msts(dat, seasonal.periods=c(7, 84), ts.frequency=7, start=2010)
```

Or

```
 tsdat <- msts(dat, seasonal.periods=c(7, 365.25), ts.frequency=7, start=2010)
```

**EDIT**

Using the provided data, looks like a decent forecast with daily/weekly seasonality.

```
data <- read.table("r_wikipedia-googletrends-model.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
dengue_index <- msts(data$dengue_index, seasonal.periods=c(7, 365), ts.frequency=7)
fit <- tbats(dengue_index)

fc <- forecast(fit)
plot(fc)
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried your last two examples. I have the same result :(.

Comment: Hmm, sorry about that.  Might try `seasonal.periods = c(7, 52, 365)`.  If you can provide a link to your actual data I can take a crack at it.

Comment: just updated my original post with a link to the data source

Comment: It worksssssss! Thank you very much :). So in your solution, as far as I understand, no need to use arima method.

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad this helped.  No, you don't need to call ARIMA directly in this method.